# How to get query into array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to get, for each `type`, the number of occurrences. You can see in the image that they are positioned at difference places based on a COUNT query I'm doing to get the data.

[image]

I am using CodeIgniter, and this is my current code, but it doesn't work.

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $num = $row->type;
    $returndata[] = array(
        'type' => $row->type,
        'num' => $row->TYPE.$num
    );
}
```

I was thinking that I could get the data with a simple foreach loop but apparently I can't. Is there some secret voodoo magic, apart from using a switch statement, to get the data?

Comment: From a distance this looks like it should work, what do you get in `$returndata` after your loop is over?

Comment: you can simply cast the object to an array- like $data =  (array)$query->result(), but i don't think that'll give you what you're looking for with the extra array element 'num'

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I was getting the same as `type`. BTW your edit is inaccurate (switch -> foreach). I meant that first thing that came to my mind was to create a switch and check the type of $row->num and based on that get a different TYPE1.2.3....

Comment: `apart from using a switch loop`: `switch` in the first place is not a loop at all, it is a conditional structure. Secondly the code that you presented as your attempt has a `foreach` loop and no switch statement anywhere. Besides, if you consider this edit changes the meaning of what you stated, please revert it back with an apology from my side

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky The switch idea was in reference to what he *could* do.  I've made a small edit to the question's formatting in order to make that more clear.

Comment: @Vulcan that makes sense but please also remove that term `loop` next to switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'num' => $row->TYPE.$num` isn't quite doing what you think it is, as that is not the correct way to access a field with a dynamic name.  In reality, you're setting `num` to the value of `$num` appended to `$row->TYPE`.

To handle dynamic object property names, you need to enclose the name in brackets:

```
'num' => $row->{'TYPE'.$num}
```

Comment: Thanks Vulcan! That's what I was looking for. Smart.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($query->result_array() as $row){

$num = $row["type"];
                    $returndata[] = array(
                        'type' => $row["type"],
                        'num' => $row["TYPE"].$num
                    );

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$returndata = [];
foreach($query->result() as $row){
    for ($i=1; $i <= 11; $i++)
    {
        if($value = $row->{'TYPE'.$i})
        {
            $returndata[$row->type] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as a side note. This will fail when there is `type>11`, no?

Comment: Yes. If you don't know how many columns there are in advance then the script will need to be changed to accustom for that. It is also assuming that only one column will have values for each row. If that is not the case, then you need to add them together (if that is what you want).

Comment: If you mean the amount of rows, then no it won't fail. For each row it goes through 11 columns in my example.